# Open Source Software to Group images by facial similarity

Tags: open-source, image-viewer, facial-recognition

Is there an open source program that will group pictures based on facial similarity?

I know there is a lot of amazing facial recognition software out there like Picasa that can group together multiple pictures of the same person.

What I'm looking for is to group together pictures of multiple people who look similar.

Sometimes in your daily life, you might think "Hmm, this person has this kind of face". This happens because we've seen quite a few people with a similar combination of facial features, say thin lips, big forehead, big eyes, bushy eyebrows, etc.